# How wifi network MITM works?

Tags: wifi, man-in-the-middle

I have seen a lot of tutorials showing how to MITM a network using various tools. But it usually says that we require a network adapter with monitor mode options.

I own my wifi router and can connect to it using a wired medium too. Can I do a MITM attack over that wifi i.e. MITM the wifi devices without using any network adapter?

For eg. can I tell my wifi router to redirect to a certain phishing page whenever someone connected to my wifi goes to `www.example.com`?

Comment: The router is already in path of the network traffic and thus is theoretically able to manipulate the traffic. If your specific router offers a way to do this is unknown though - it would need to have the necessary software installed (unlikely) or have a way to install such software (rarely) or would need to have some way to pass the traffic through some external system for manipulation (rarely). Even if such ways exists redirecting traffic will only be feasible for plain HTTP and not for HTTPS, unless the client trusts the MITM.

Comment: OP, WRT to the comment by @SteffenUllrich above, where it reads, `If your specific router offers a way to do this is unknown though - it would need to have the necessary software installed (unlikely)` - There is a device called a `Piineapple` that is designed for this purpose.  See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/204723/wi-fi-pineapple-device-is-it-that-easy-to-steal-peoples-info for more info.

Comment: Your last line is a very specific attack that has nothing to do with wifi or mitm. If ***that*** is your goal, then you can re-write your question about that.